# Jquery - bootstrap tabs not changing on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal for a form that needs to be filled out in two steps . 
Inside the modal , i am using tabs to display the two forms . 
Below is my ul inside the modal body :

```
<ul id="example-user-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
<li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#form1_details" data-toggle="tab">FORM1</a></li>
<li id="tab2"><a href="#questionaire" data-toggle="tab">Questionaire</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below are how the tab panes are defined :

```
 <div class="tab-pane active in" id="form1_details">
<div class="tab-pane active in" id="questionaire">
```

Both the above panes have forms inside them . Now the manual changing of the tabs work fine but not via jquery programming .

Inside the first form , i have a link that when clicked upon, should switch the tabs :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="to_questionaire">Next</a>
```

And below is what i am doing via jquery to switch the tabs .But for some reason nothing happens at all .

```
$("#to_questionaire").click(function(){
        $('#example-user-tabs a[href="#questionaire"]').tab('show');
    });
```

Would be great if someone knows how to go about this .

NOTE : Please do not mark this as duplicate as none of the solutions from Stackoverflow threads have solved my problem . I have done them all .

Comment: Can you post a working example link?

Comment: Seems like all these expert's expertise go for a toss when a tricky question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you have wrong id in your js cause there is no 'to_questions' in HTML

and working code should look like this

```
$("#to_questionaire").on('click',function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#example-user-tabs li').next('li').find('a[href="#questionaire"]').addClass('active').tab('show');
    });
```

Comment: I have changed it ...was a mistake . Changing the ids is not the point of concern . It still does not work .